# Reduce the size of resultant with polynomial of two variables.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, resultant

I have a problem in which I have to calculate given two polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ a polynomial with roots the product of the roots of $f$ and $g$. My reasoning shows that this reduces to calculate the resultant of the following two polynomials in $Y$: $$x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4$$ and $$y^2+y+1$$ However, I don't want to compute a $6 \times 6$ determinant but I would rather prefer to work as the following property suggest ($R$ is the resultant):

> Given $p,q \in A[X]$ with $r$ the euclidean remainder of $q$ by $p$,
>   we have $R(p,q) = a_n^{m-gr(r)} R(p,r)$.

But my first polynomial is a polynomial in two variables. How can I deal with this situation?

Comment: You have to decide with respect to which variable you want to take the resultant, i.e., which variable you want to eliminate.  ([See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Application_to_polynomial_systems).)  Probably you want to think of these as polynomials in $y$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.